# AmStockChart indicator on the chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I can't add indicator line on the [AmStockChart](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart)
I'm trying to add multiple [DataSet](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/DataSet)s in [AmStockChart.dataSets](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#dataSets) property like this:

```
....  
firstDataSet.fieldMappings = [
  { fromField: "open", toField: "open" },
  { fromField: "high", toField: "high" },
  { fromField: "low", toField: "low" },
  { fromField: "close", toField: "close" },
  { fromField: "volume", toField: "volume" }
];
....
secondDataSet.fieldMappings = [ { fromField: "value", toField: "value" } ];
....  
chart.dataSets = [ firstDataSet, secondDataSet ];
```

But after graph initializing I can see only first candlestick graph.

How can I add indicator line on AmStockChart?

Comment: I am afraid this is too little to tell where the problem is. Have you followed this tutorial? http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/moving-average-indicators-for-stock-chart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@zeroin shows me [a good solution](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/moving-average-indicators-for-stock-chart/). There is no need to add new `DataSet`. You can use existing `DataSet` but add to it new `field` like:

```
// exactly dataSet can be not first
// "indicator_" + i - field name
chart.dataSets[ 0 ].fieldMappings.push({
  fromField: "indicator_" + i,
  toField: "indicator_" + i
});
```

And then add your calculated `value` to its field:

```
for ( var j = 0; j < chart.dataSets[ 0 ].dataProvider.length; j ++ ) {
  // calculate value  
  chart.dataSets[ 0 ].dataProvider[ j ][ "indicator_" + i ] = value.toFixed( 4 );  
}
```

And add new `StockGraph` to `StockPanel`:

```
var indicatorGraph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
indicatorGraph.valueField = "indicator_" + i;
indicatorGraph.useDataSetColors = false;
indicatorGraph.type = "smoothedLine";
stockPanel.addStockGraph( indicatorGraph );
```

Then call `chart.validateNow();`.